# Is it possible to get a detailed query when delete operation fails?

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am doing a delete operation with a filter of 2 fields:

```
const query = await Flow.deleteOne({
    _id: flowId,
    permissions: currentUser!.id,
});
```

Then I check the query object that returns from this operation to determine whether the operation was successful or not:

```
if (!query.deletedCount) {
    throw new BadRequestError("Flow not found");
}
```

The problem is that I cant know if the operation failed because the flowId is wrong (first filter field) or the user don't have permissions (second filter field).

Is there an option to get a more detailed query result in mongoose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see from the official [docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-deleteOne), `deleteOne` returns an object with three properties:

- `ok` `1` if no errors
- `deletedCount` number of docs deleted
- `n` number of docs deleted

If you need to investigate the reasons for the failure you could query the database in case of error, something like:

```
if (!query.deletedCount) {
    const flow = await Flow.findById(flowId);
    // wrong `flowId`
    if (!flow) throw new BadRequestError("Flow not found");
    // otherwise, user don't have permission
    throw new BadRequestError("Unauthorized");
}
```